# Why is Batman's policy on saving people inconsistent?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy

I'm of course referring to the Nolan trilogy. At the end of Batman Begins he

> said to Ra’s Al Ghul *"I won't kill you but I don't have to save you"* and left him on the train that eventually crashes.

However, he

> saves the Joker from the fall at the end of The Dark Knight, and the Joker says *"You just couldn't let me go, could you?"*

Why? Even though Ra's Al Ghul wanted to kill more people, the Joker succeeded in killing more people (including Rachel) and corrupting a symbol of hope that is Harvey, turning him into Two-Face.

Comment: Because Ra tried to judge him...

Comment: Why put a spoiler warning in your question title, if that very same title spoils it? See also: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/to-spoiler-or-not-to-spoiler-june-2014-edition and http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers

Comment: @SarpSTA: you tried, and you failed. The lesson is: [never try](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwVNuyfhF0Q&t=0m06s). (I’m kidding.)

Comment: @BMWurm the most applicable meta discussion in this case is [Is it okay to have spoilers in question titles?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/835/is-it-okay-to-have-spoilers-in-question-titles)

Comment: @phantom42 I must have had selective blindness... I was sure that I had seen that one before yet couldn't find it... so I took the next best thing. :P

Comment: I too am tired of this constant flip-flopping from Batman.

Comment: Not really a full answer, but could it have something to do with the fact that the Joker is clinically insane and as such not truly in control of his own actions, where as Ra is perfectly sane?

Comment: related, possible dupe: [Why didn't Batman just kill Joker when he had the chance?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87283/5184)

Comment: see also: [In comics does Batman have a rule against killing?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58620/5184)

Comment: @phantom42 I don't think my question is really a duplicate of the one you suggest. Everybody knows Batman doesn't kill. But if letting people die is something he does, why didn't do the same with Joker?

Comment: Character development

Answer (score 7):

He isn't inconsistent about saving people, he's consistent about not killing them.

### TL;DR:  Ra's drove himself off a ledge, but Batman *threw* the Joker off a building.

That is to say, Ra's Al Ghul *killed himself*, but if the Joker had fallen to his death, he would have been killed *by Batman*.

---

#### How did Ra's die?

He stole a train and drove off a ledge, killing him;  Batman escaped the train at the last second.  Batman didn't do this to Ra's, he was just there when Ra's did it.  Ra's killed himself, and Batman let him do it.  Batman didn't kill anyone.

---

#### How did the Joker fall?

Batman threw him out of a building.  The Joker didn't jump.  He wasn't driving a train off a broken track.  He was standing in a building, and Batman threw him out.  If the Joker had fallen to his death, Batman would have borne all the responsibility for the death.  Batman would have killed him.

---

### From Batman's perspective, these two situations are *very* different.  "Crazy villain drives his stolen train off a ledge, and I don't stop him" versus "Crazy villain has specifically said he will not kill me, but I still murder him by throwing him off a building".

Comment: But at the same time, Gordon is the one that destroys the train track under guidance from batman, so in effect, Batman is the reason the train is flying of the rails. So he is in fact, directly responsible for Ra's death.

Answer (score 6):

It's time and reaction.

In the case of Ras, after the fight, Bats find himself in the position to choose to rescue him or just letting him die. He can cool down and make a decision.

When the Joker falls, he reacts instinctively and grab him. He doesn't have time to think and reacts driven by it's true nature (not to kill). Once he has the Joker, he cannot let him go, as it'll be a cool blooded killing.

First situation could seem quite hypocritical, and it is. However, this is the explanation to your question. The reason why he doesn't let the joker drop is because he reacts instinctively.

Comment: You referring to Batman as Bats had me like "OMG MR. J? <3". Back to reality, I think Batman had more time in Joker's case. In the former one he is in a train that's going to kill him if he doesn't leave in seconds. In the latter, Joker says *"Did I tell you how I got these scars?"* and Batman says *"No but I know how you go these!"* and uses those things on his arm which indicates he planned to strike him like that before doing so.

Comment: But probably didn't expect to throw him over the building, otherwise he won't reacted as he did.

Comment: He didn't try to do anything else though. Right after hitting him and catching him off-guard he threw him off. I think that was pretty planned.

Comment: @SarpSTA: Batman threw the Joker off the building? If so, he kinda had to catch him, otherwise his action would have killed him. Whereas with Ra’s, Batman didn’t start the train going or anything.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I thought of that too. But here's the thing. He blamed himself for people that Joker has killed because he didn't turn himself in. So he **didn't** actually kill people but their death was caused by him not acting. If he considers that as *his fault* then he should also take responsibility for Ra's. But he doesn't. Instead of saving him, he leaves him to death. But he doesn't do it with Joker. One can claim Ra's brought himself to the train and Batman didn't start it. But Joker also got to the edge of building on his own. Pushed Batman to a level that he has to throw him off.

Comment: @SarpSTA: “He blamed himself for people that Joker has killed because he didn't turn himself in.” Did he? I don’t remember that being suggested in the movie.

Comment: Batman:You’re gonna hold a press conference tomorrow morning.
Dent: Why?
Batman: **No one else will die because of me.** Gotham’s in your hands now.
Dent: You can’t. You can’t give in. You can’t give in!

Comment: Another explanation is that, with all those stealth members of the League of Shadows, Batman cannot arrest Ra's Al Ghul and transfer him to the police without a risk of him escaping. On the other side, Joker is an insane lone man, with a few henchmen that are not likely to take risks for his life.

Answer (score 3):

The Joker wanted Batman to kill him.

> "You just couldn't let me go, could you?"

If Batman had let him fall he would have won - succeeded in proving his 'sick philosophy' was correct.

> BATMAN: I have one rule.
>
> JOKER: Then that's the one rule you'll have to break to know the
>   truth.
>
> BATMAN: Which is?
>
> JOKER: The only sensible way to live in this world is without rules.
>   And tonight you're gonna break your one rule.

It probably would have been more sensible to kill him, given how dangerous he was, but that is precisely the unprincipled utilitarianism the joker is espousing. After the incredible bravery of everyone on the ferries defying the Joker's game, it would be poor form for Batman to immediately give in to it.

Batman is better than the Joker ("more than just a man") because he has his rules - what kind of message does it send if the symbol immediately abandons them when it gets a little tough?

(Or to put it another way, Batman wasn't 'just' trying to save the city like with Al Ghul - the Joker entered into a massive scheme to tear down the belief in things Batman stands for, so Batman has to fight back accordingly (and makes the ending very ironic!))