# Was Batman going to shoot Joe Chill?

Tags: dc, batman

In Batman Year Two, Batman takes Joe Chill to the alley where he murdered his parents. He shows him his identity and points a gun at him and claims he will kill him. At that moment the reaper shoots and kills Chill. Was Batman actually going to kill Chill? Has Batman ever intentionally killed anyone before? Batman then goes on to battle the Reaper and he uses the gun on him, so that's one rule of his he has broken.

UPDATE: I believe whether Batman has a rule of killing or not varies heavily depending on the continuity. So for this question let's focus on the continuity of Year Two/Year One.

Comment: Batman has killed plenty of people in the past especially in older comics.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58620/in-comics-does-batman-have-a-rule-against-killing/58625#58625

Comment: It's my assumption he was going to kill Chill.

Comment: My guess is "No. Or else, he would not be the Batman" but the problem is that the writing of Year Two is somewhat inconsistent with the character (Batman decides that he needs a gun after getting his ass kicked). I don't if it is possible to know for sure if he would have dropped his no-killing rule for Chill as fast as his no-gun policy, specially in the context of that story (Batman has faced Chill before in [other stories](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=batman+joe+chill&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#)).

Comment: @DoctorWho22 I guess it depends on the continuity. For example, in Knightfall where Bane breaks Batman's back, he goes to great lengths to not kill anyone.