# Batman breaking his own rule against killing

Tags: batman, dc-extended-universe, dc, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Why has Zack Snyder's [Batman v Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice) shown brazen killings by Batman?

It might have been okay if the killings were not direct, but he shoots and blasts off individuals by directly targeting them in the movie.

Does it depend on the personal choice of the artist or Batman has no such rules or does he have a different set of rules that I didn't understood correctly?

I mean if the DCEU is involved, shouldn't the character be more sticked to the DC comics version of Batman?

Comment: [In comics does Batman have a rule against killing?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58620/5184)

Comment: @phantom42 well I am more concerned about the way he went rouge in the movie and killed lots of guys, lot more than he killed in the entire DC Comic Series

Comment: You asked if he should be "more stuck to the dc comics version of batman". The answers on the other question point out that he has a history of killing people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly depends on the version of Batman or indirectly the artist(comics/script writer).

In-fact [Batman did kill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXywZJ8BSTc), and it's all part of the [comics](https://fromthegoddamnbatfans.quora.com/The-Dark-Knight-Returns-vs-Dawn-of-Justice) [too](http://i.newsarama.com/images/i/000/119/898/i300/batman-kills-mad-monk.jpg). But again, Batman choosing a gun is paradoxical, as you might have looked at that

> nightmare dream sequence during which the pearls of necklace of his mother, Martha Wayne, are loaded into the pistol instead of bullets.

As far as Zack Snyder's Batman is concerned, he gave [an interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0ZD6Wmu2L8) in which he explained that why he made his version of Batman so brutal. To be honest, [I couldn't buy it](https://www.quora.com/Reviews-of-Batman-v-Superman-Dawn-of-Justice-2016-movie/review/Anubhav-Balodhi).

Update: [Zack Snyder on death of Robin](https://www.facebook.com/dcmovieuniverse/videos/546048805556440/) explains the current psychological state of Batman. I'm not saying that he is psychotic, but he is definitely unstable, and all this justifies the beast(pun definitely not intended) he has become.
But it is similar to that of [Alfred Tennyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Memoriam_A.H.H.). When you lose someone you care about, you are vulnerable to [emotional setback](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/get-hardy/201309/about-complicated-bereavement-disorder-0).
Thus, he is not the same Batman. He is more brutal, his killer instincts are at peak. 
But hopefully, Batman will get over with it, after all. [He is vengeance! He am the night! He is the goddamn Batman!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xbbpH-20ak)

Comment: That interview really gives a pretty good explanation. From the director's perspective, he actually toned it down a bit.

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, but again. It also shows the mental state of Batman who has lost Robin, he is more fierce and dark. Would he kill to save a single hostage? Yes or No, this is an important question.

Comment: Psychologically, he probably felt like he was saving his own mother, also named Martha. Additionally, he just promised the most powerful being on the planet that he would save her while he saved the world, so that's some additional serious motivation.

Comment: Yes exactly. That scene was crux of the whole movie (at least for me).

Answer (score 3):

To address your point about Batman killing, then we will have to dig a little deep into the dream sequence before the flash appears...

The dream or to be more exact,a point in distant future,where superman has gone rogue because Lois has been killed is an indication that the DCEU is following the *Injustice* storyline.

The soldiers who are killed by Batman by gunfire are enhanced by abilities given to them by a pill which the Man of Steel has created to resurrect an army of his own.

So even if Batman is shown shooting at them point blank,they wont be killed as they are enhanced.

But since Zack would want to bring his own taste to the mix of DCEU, the flying creatures in the sequence suggest that Superman has either knowingly or out of choice has created an alliance with DARKSEID.

Now this is new as their is no such allegiance in the comicsverse.

Now coming back to the point where Batman has to kill the Russian to save Martha is an indication or rather a tribute to the comics where in some dream of Superman after the death of Lois, batman kills Joker, his nemesis,to save Lois and therefore prevents Superman from going rogue...

P.S:Do correct me if i missed something :)

Comment: I think the allegiance with Darkseid is more of a compulsion where superman is under control of Darkseid, (As we can see in Justice League: War).
However its a little different version of it.