# Does Clark Kent know who Bruce Wayne is in this scene?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Clark Kent approaches Bruce Wayne and asks,

> What is your position on bat vigilante in Gotham?

Is this because he knows who Bruce Wayne is? Because there is not much reason to ask someone who is considered a playboy billionaire their opinion on crime. Maybe a Senator or someone connected to the law, but not Bruce Wayne???

Comment: Bruce Wayne is a prominent public figure in Gotham, it is known that his parents were murdered by a thug and he is insanely rich - why not ask him? Plus, if my memory serves me well, in one of the comics Supes actually figured out Batman's identity on his own - being super-smart alien and a reporter has its perks, as it would seem. Plus, Bruce actually *owns* Daily Planet - why not ask the biggest boss there is his opinion?

Comment: Plus, Superman can detect heartbeat rates. Batman is a trained ...master of many things, and he was calmly moving about, intent on planting an electronic device (isn't this that scene?), but "keeping calm" is different than "being calm naturally". Maybe Superman detected this also? Plus whatever Gallifreian mentioned above.

Comment: Guys, if experienced journalist KyloRen thinks there’s not much reason to ask, then *there’s not much reason to ask*.

Comment: Not sure Bruce owns the Planet in the movie universe - he asks distractedly if he owns it, "or is it the other guy?"

Now that begs the question of who "the other guy" could be.  Considering we're clearly heading towards Darkseid in the ongoing narrative, he could be referring to Morgan Edge, who started as a super-rick lackey of Darkseid, owner of Galaxy Communications.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, oh, that's right, no stupid questions on this site....Silly me, here I thought we were on StackOvereflow, there you are rewarded for a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unlikely

There is no indication that Clark knew that Bruce is Batman in this scene.  As Gallifreian pointed out in the comment below your question, Bruce Wayne is a prominent figure in Gotham, and it is normal for reporters to ask prominent figures what they think about events in their cities.

It is implied that Clark first becomes suspicious of Bruce Wayne a little later at the party, when his super-hearing detects Alfred speaking in Bruce's earpiece.

(See also the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123222/why-did-luthor-care-about-this-person/).)